# New Jobs tab location

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I've signed up for the "beta" where the Jobs tab now appears in the top navigation bar here:

[image: Jobs Tab Location]

Now, I've been using the site for about 8 months and I've developed a "muscle memory" for my mouse to click the "Tags" tab then select the tag I want to view. I now find myself accidentally hitting the "Jobs" tab quite often by mistake.

What I would propose is to move the "Jobs" tab to the end.

[image: Jobs Tab New Location]

To me, it doesn't make any sense to have it nestled in between "Questions" and "Tags". I like that its in the navigation bar now, but I'm not going to find myself checking it more than once a day or two, so I'd place it towards the end of the existing navigation buttons.

Comment: Personally, since this is not related to  site contents, I would like to see it separated, e.g. making it aligned to the left side of the whole header

Comment: I'd be open to placing it wherever it works best, I just don't think that its current position is intuitive. Even if it was placed between "Badges" and "Ask A Question" that would be better than where it is now.

Comment: @RonBeyer agreed - it makes a lot of sense IMO to have the 'Ask Question' button all the way at the end where it's easy to find.

Comment: Wherever you move it you're going to mess with someone's muscle memory. So unless you move it off that menu completely (not suggesting that is a good idea) then it doesn't matter. Can't you just get used to it? Muscle memory will adapt pretty quickly.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I'm sure I'll adapt, but its current location doesn't make good sense. Why between "questions" and "tags"? Even if you place it as the first tab that would be fine, but it has no relation to the item on its right or left, where-as questions is related to tags...

Comment: The first part of the question is basically another version of [spacebar heating](https://xkcd.com/1172/). I agree with the second part, but it will need an additional horizontal space.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Indeed it is a break in my workflow, so I guess another option would be for SO to give me an option to rearrange the nav bar for my login, that would work too :) Custom navbars for everyone!

Comment: @RonBeyer It's amazing what you can do with [userscripts](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/5ad388fd807a516b24bb) nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Status Declined only because this specific implementation is not happening.

There is an entire navigation project that incorporates both Jobs and Documentation that is underway.  Once Documentation enters public beta the entire top level navigation will be addressed.  Until then, we're unlikely to fuss with the location of the Jobs tab.